# Does "stopping" imply permanence?

Tags: meaning

I have a friend who believes that I can't say I **stopped** smoking as I have taken it up again (I have given it up and taken it up again a few times before).

I believe that I can say, "I gave up smoking", and that "I stopped smoking", even if I had/have taken up/begun this foul addiction again.

Examples:

> I stopped smoking 30 years ago, but I have taken it up again a few times since then.
>
> I gave up smoking 30 years ago, but I took it up again.

Just because I have taken up smoking again, does it mean that I can't say I **stopped** smoking at a particular time in the past?

That is, is *stopping* permanent, or can it be temporary?

Comment: I have a number of acquaintances who have stopped and/or given up smoking any number of times - only to take it up again. It was only on the tenth attempt that I finally stopped/gave it up myself

Comment: It is completely legit to say "I stopped smoking a month ago, but unfortunately I've taken it up again", or something of that nature.  If you stop at a stop light that doesn't imply you won''t go again, when it turns green. "Gave up" implies a slightly more permanent scenario, but does not mandate that one did not backslide.

Answer (score 5):

It can certainly be temporary. When you stop a car at a stop sign you expect to start again. You also stop working to take a lunch break, stop cooking when the food is ready etc. etc.

An example closer to yours - if a mother doesn't smoke while pregnant but starts again she's often described as having stopped doing while expecting the baby.

I'd actually say that *stopping* is less likely to imply not restarting than *giving up*. Though in the case of smoking everyone knows it's hard to give up; the intention to stop forever defines what's happening more than whether or not it's successful.

Comment: The car example is what I exactly had in mind when I saw this question. +1.

Comment: "Stopping by Woods on a Snowy Evening"